# How to compute the derivative of a matrix algebra expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares

I came across a question pertaining to finding the derivative of a particular matrix expression. [How do you compute the derivative of a matrix algebra expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825438/how-do-you-compute-the-derivative-of-a-matrix-algebra-expression)

The article the question refers to can be found at: https://web.archive.org/web/20180403213813/http://jimherold.com/2012/04/20/least-squares-bezier-fit/

Anyway, I am wondering if the logic from the answer (and thus the derivative) applies to other matrix expressions of the form 
$$E(C_y) = (y - \mathbb{T}MC_y)^T(y - \mathbb{T}MC_y)$$
or if there is something special about the matrix M (potentially that it is lower triangular?) that causes the derivative to be 
$$\frac{\partial E} {\partial C} = -2\mathbb{T}^T(y-\mathbb{T}MC_y)$$

In particular, if M is not triangular, would the derivative be the same? And if not, how could one find it?

Comment: In your gradient, you are missing matrix $M$. It should be $$\frac{\partial E} {\partial C_y} = -2(\mathbb{T}M)^T(y-\mathbb{T}MC_y) \ .$$ Also, I don't think it needs to have any structure.

Comment: @user550103 Thanks, do you mind explaining how you got that answer?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2128462/339790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, some facts and notations:

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B C\right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TBC) := A : B C$$
- Cyclic properties of Trace/Frobenius product 
  \begin{align}
  A : B C D
   &= (BC)^T A : D \\
   &= BCD   :  A  \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

So, we can rewrite the cost function in Frobenius product notation as
$$E(C_y) := (y - \mathbb{T}MC_y)^T(y - \mathbb{T}MC_y) = (y - \mathbb{T}MC_y) : (y - \mathbb{T}MC_y) \ .$$

Now, we can obtain the differential first, and then the gradient.
\begin{align}
dE(C_y)  
&= d\left( y - \mathbb{T}MC_y : y - \mathbb{T}MC_y \right) \\
&= \left( -\mathbb{T}M \ dC_y : y - \mathbb{T}MC_y \right)  + \left( y - \mathbb{T}MC_y :  - \mathbb{T}M \  dC_y \right) \\
&= 2 \left( y - \mathbb{T}MC_y \right) :  -\mathbb{T}M \  dC_y  \\
&= -2 \left( \mathbb{T}M \right)^T \left( y - \mathbb{T}MC_y \right) :  dC_y \\
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial E(C_y)}{\partial C_y} = -2 \left( \mathbb{T}M \right)^T \left( y - \mathbb{T}MC_y \right).
\end{align}